# Maven Tags doubts

Tags: maven

Hi all as i am new to maven project so can any body clear me about the tags as what i am thinking is that "  " is name of the package where you want to keep your source codes and   is  the tag where we are mentioning project name for example without using maven we are creating a project through eclipse so we foolow the following steps

1-> new project

2->project name (in case of maven this comes under  tag)

3->we create a package name for keeping source codes inside it (in case of maven this comes under  tag )

so like this we proceed in our developmennt.

please sujjest me whether my understanding is correct as i have described above.
waiting for your reply

Comment: Can you rephrase your question more clearly? Right now it's quite confusing - what do you mean by 'tags'? Also, there's a blank that looks like you didn't copy or type in the question correctly: '...what i am thinking is that " " is name of the package...'

Comment: Do you want to get the basic understanding of Maven project creation and all?

Comment: 333kenshin..  actualy i have missed something in above question  actualy i am trying to understand  how to start a new maven project but so far from my current understanding what i came to know is that the groupId tag used in pom.xml that  we can relate to as package names in our normal project example com.sk.automotive (without maven ) and for artifactId tag used in pom.xml we can relate it to as a name of our project example mySpringProject(without maven)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to know some basic things about MAVEN project.

Like how to Create a maven project.

How is its directory Structure,etc.

Let me help you with it.

- New Maven Project
- Give some name,select type of packaging from dropdown(jar/war/pom)
- Once project created add  to your POM file.
- Write web.xml(dispatcher servlet)(src->main->webapp->WEB-INF)
- Write you Code in some package.

You need Maven installed on your eclipse and also you must set user settings.

**INSTALLING MAVEN**

- Click *Install new software* option on your eclipse. You can find it under **HELP tab**.
- search "maven for eclipse kepler" and install that particular setup.
- Now once done open "preferences" Under Maven->Installation browse to the Apache-maven path wherever you have saved it.
- Now change User setting,give path of your settings.xml(this xml has path of your repository)

Now you are done with installaion.

I hope this is answer to your queation as your question is already very confusing.

Comment: Hi Veke thanks for replying you are correct i like to know basic thinghs in maven what ever you have explained i understood that but  i have one doubt that is how to install Maven on my  eclipse keepler and also how to  set user settings. please can you tell me that one also.

Comment: @shwetank installing maven is simple process See my updated answer

Comment: ok veke actualy i am new to stackoverflow thats why i did not know how to accept answers but now i came to know by exploring in google